# Git credential helper doesn't work

Tags: linux, git, authentication, credentials, opensuse

I've just installed openSUSE, which came with Git version 1.8.1.4.

I'm trying to push some repository after having configured the credential helper with this line:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

This line doesn't throw any errors.

However, after I enter my credentials initially, and expect to get them cached, the credential helper does not work. It spits out this message:

```
error: cannot run git-credential-cache--daemon: No such file or directory  
fatal: unable to start cache daemon: No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install the `git-daemon` rpm.  That RPM has the cache daemon.